# Java EE too big content size of response

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, enterprise

probably my screens can explain it more better.

My question is what I am doing wrong or how to analyze more the response from my Java Servlet? I am having troubles with waiting too much for response. Even caching mechanism does not work enough for me. There should be a problem somewhere else in sending data from server to the jsp page.

Here's the response size from chrome inspector:
[image]

and here you can see that I am sending just some HashMaps and ArrayLists back to  the jsp page to be displayed. Can u pls help me or navigate me how to analyze more deeply where is the problem? between the dispatcher and jsp or too much data in the arrays? How to get the actual size of an array in MB?
[image]

**EDIT** based on comments. Here is the picture of structure of tabs being dynamically created in loops in tracking.jsp file(the file itself is quite big 1700 lines of code):
[image]

Comment: Take a look at `tracking.jsp` and see what it does with those attributes. It can create huge loops for example, resulting in a gigantic response.

Comment: Yes I am having loops there, is this a bad practise? I am having even few nested loops within.

Comment: Well it depends what you're doing with the loops. If you have 3 maps with 100 items each, and you're doing a nested loop with all of them, you'll go through `100³ = 1M` iterations. If each iteration prints out 100 bytes of text, you'll get a nice 100MB chunk generated there.

Comment: yes, something similar is hapening there infact, but the expected loops are not more than 10. So I think you found out my problem! Do you have a suggestion for this problem? I am having some tabs and need something similiar to this: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/creating-dinamics-tabs-jquery-jstl    But for tabs the loops are the only solution.

Comment: I've given you plenty of suggestions. You'll need to do some of the work yourself. Look at the jsp and see if the logic is wrong.

Comment: ok I think I need to find out another solution for displaying the data in the front end rather than count on jsp to be rendered. Thanks

Comment: Well you could post your `tracking.jsp`. It's where the problem is, not the code you're displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigations the problem were the loops I was using in my tracking.jsp file for bootstrap tabs and nested tabs, so I have implemented jQGrid framework for data processing and switching data with different abstraction. Big thanks to @Kayaman for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

Try removing `return` statement after `forward` call. `Flush` and `close` the `writer` and remove `return` in else block.

Note: I assume that this code is present in one of the HttpServlet's method.

Comment: Why do you think any of that will make a difference?